# How to set environment variable can access anytime using powershell?

Tags: powershell, command, environment-variables

I have text file with this format `12345` .
I want to set that value as environment variable that I can access it even the powershell closed. 
My expectation when I want to access that environment variable from command line, I just use this command : `echo %ID%` and I t will show `12345`

```
$file = Get-Content .\file.txt
$Variable = "ID"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("$Variable", "$file")
```

#### Update Code

I tried this, but I still cant get the environment variable with this command from command line : `echo %ID%`

```
$file = Get-Content .\file.txt
$Variable = "ID"

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("$Variable", "$file",1)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("$Variable", "$file","User")
```

Comment: Updated Code  is working now. need to close the cmd first, then do the checking of environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable` allows you to choose the Environment Variable Target. The default is the current process, so calling with two arguments only makes the variable available to the current PowerShell session.

If you have permissions you can enable the Environment Variable at the machine level (2), either:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("$Variable", "$file",2)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("$Variable", "$file","Machine")
```

Or, just the user level (1), either:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("$Variable", "$file",1)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("$Variable", "$file","User")
```

- The 'Machine Level' is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` in the registry.
- The 'User Level' is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I updated the code, Is that what you mean? But It still not working as my expectation @mjsqu

Comment: You may find that you need to restart cmd to get the environment variable to show up

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify the target environment. by default, that static method only sets the $Var/value pair for the current process. you likely want that for the current user, so use the 2nd method listed in the 1st link below with the target set to `user`. here are the doc pages ...

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable Method (System) | Microsoft Docs
— https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.7.2

EnvironmentVariableTarget Enum (System) | Microsoft Docs
— https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I cant figure it out with this solution :(

Comment: @Job - it's identical to the one provided by mjsqu. [*grin*] just add the required 3rd parameter to the call - `User` or `1` as you prefer.

Comment: I updated it. But It is not working as my expectation.
My expectation, after I run the `powershell script`, I go to `cmd` and use this command `echo %ID%` it will show `12345` @Lee_Dailey

Comment: @Job Did you keep your cmd open? After setting an environment variable you need to close and re-open the commandbox. Otherwise it will not look at the changes.

Comment: Yes. It works now. I need to close the cmd first after execute the powershell script.
Thanks All...

Comment: @Job - as Theo pointed out, your _current_ env settings will not change with that technique, only the master for that user/system will be modified.